# How to fire events on multiple layers of custom components with react unit testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm writing a test case for a feature I'm unit testing. I want to edit a text field that's embedded within several custom components but I can't figure out how to access it:

## TestFile.test.tsx

```
it('should be able to change quantity', () =>{
  //Mock out dependent function with jest
  //Nothing here right now


  //Render with the props you want
  render(        
        <MainComponent /> );

  //Locate screen components for test
  const counter = screen.queryByTestId("counter");

  //Perform user actions
  fireEvent.change(counter, 4);   <--This is the line where I'm trying to access what I want

  //Measure against expect cases
  expect(counter).toBe(4);
});
```

## MainComponent.tsx

This is the component I'm trying to access. The problem is, `fireEvent.change` won't work because it's a custom component. At least, I think that's why it doesn't work.

```
<Counter
  data-testid='counter'    <--data-testid is here right now
  containerMargin={{ marginTop: -5 }}
/>
```

## Counter.tsx

Inside `Counter` is another custom component, `TextField`

```
<TextField
     {...props}
/>
```

## TextField.tsx

And inside TextField is where the text input I want to access is:

```
<TextInput
  {...props}
/>
```

## Error Message

When I try to run the test, I get this error:

```
  ●  Test › should be able to change quantity

Unable to fire a "change" event - please provide a DOM element.

  189 |
  190 |     //Perform user actions
> 191 |     fireEvent.change(counter, 4);
      |               ^
  192 |
  193 |     //Measure against expect cases
  194 |     expect(counter).toBe(4);
```

I can't put the `data-testid` property inside `TextField` or the `TextInput` itself, because there's another `Counter` in the render of the page I'm testing. Any advice or troubleshooting would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the [tag:html] tag with [tag:react-testing-library]

Answer (score 3):

[The `getByTestId` query is an escape hatch.](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid#api)

> In the spirit of the guiding principles, it is recommended to use this only after the other queries don't work for your use case. Using data-testid attributes do not resemble how your software is used and should be avoided if possible.

Your text field should be accessible. And the [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility) should be leveraged to access the element.

```js
const input = screen.getByRole('textbox', {name: t('priceMultiple')})
// or
const input = screen.getByLabelText(t('priceMultiple'))
```

[Using `fireEvent` directly is also an escape hatch.](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events)

> Most projects have a few use cases for `fireEvent`, but the majority of the time you should probably use `@testing-library/user-event`.

This recommendation is further explained [in the `user-event` docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro#difference-to-fireevent) and [in this blog post](https://ph-fritsche.github.io/blog/post/why-userevent).

```js
await userEvent.type(input, '4')
```

Note that setting up a user-event instance and describing the exact workflow a user performs on the component is recommended for most cases. So most tests should look something like this.

```js
const user = userEvent.setup()
render(<MyComponent/>)

await user.tripleClick(screen.getByRole('textbox', {name: /some label/}))
await user.keyboard('4')

// ... assert that the component output is correct ...

await user.tab()
await user.keyboard('567') // edit another field

// ... perform more assertions ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking , you are right, adding `data-testid` to a React component is useless unless you propagate this prop down to the DOM element.
Luckily for you `<TextField />` accepts `inputProps` which it propagates to the `<input />` element.

For example

```js
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <ChildComponent data-testid="counter" />
  );
}

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      inputProps={{ "data-testid": props["data-testid"] }}
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Outlined"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
};
```

Then you can use `getByTestId` in tests.

```
test("should be able to trigger input change", () => {
  render(<BasicTextFields />);
  const input = screen.getByTestId("counter");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "23" } });
  expect(input.value).toBe("23");
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-joliot-0f49v?file=/src/App.js

I didn't create the deep hierarchy you created to make my answer cleaner but as long as you propagate the props down to the `<TextField />` you should be good. You can also use [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) but this is out of this answer's scope.

Comment: So this requires me to use the TextField component, but my framework is already built around using TextInput, and there are too many issues if I try to change it

Comment: I just relized and I'm a bit confused because you mention: [tag:react-native] and react-testing-library but react-testing-library doesn't support web. [tag:react-native-testing-library] is the react-native flavor of testing-library. So what is it?

Comment: @testing-library/react is the package I've been using for testing, but TextInput comes from 'react-native-gesture-handler', so it's been proving difficult to test with. I've finally got it to a point where I can target it, but now I can't change the value inside it

Comment: Why are you not using `react-native-testing-library`? Isn't `fireEvent.change` working? Are you able to trigger events in different places in your app?

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a long time to respond. I am using the the package @testing-library/react. Not @testing-library/react-native. The react-native one doesn't allow me to use screen.getBy() calls on the completed render. I haven't been able to get fireEvent.change to work though, but I did get fireEvent.click to work for something else.